# What is difference between LinkedHashSet and FilterSet(Guava)

Tags: guava, linkedhashset

When I trace legacy code, I found something very strange. I can get all the data values from LinkedHashSet, not from the other(FilterSet).

Although data can be seen in unfiltered, but in iteration, I cannot get the required data. Is it because of the predicate? How to get all the data from unfiltered ones?

I found that **guava** is used in the implementation of utilities class in my project.

What is the difference of these two sets? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
Set<A<? extends B, ?>> attributes;
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if `FilterSet` is a built-in class. Can you check your legacy code for `FiltereSet`'s implementation?

Answer (score 1):

`Sets.filter` returns a private implementation type called `FilteredSet` that is a *view* of another set, restricting its output to only the elements of the original set that have some particular property.

There is deliberately no way to get out the original unfiltered data.